# Apple App Store not showing correct icon in iOS 7

Tags: app-store, ios7, app-store-connect, xcode5, itunesartwork

I've updated one of my apps to support both iOS6 and iOS7. After the update was approved, the icon for the app in search results is incorrect on iOS7.

[image: not-correct]

[image: correct]

As you can see, the icon is correct on the app page, but not correct in the search results page (you can tell by the rounded corners). It is showing the iOS6 icon in the search results.

I setup the icons for the projects with the new method that uses the Images.xcassets folder. In iTunesConnect, I uploaded the new icon, and the `iTunesArtwork` and `iTunesArtwork@2x` files are both the correct versions.

I'm fairly convinced this is an issue on Apple's end. Here is a thread on another website about the same issue:
[iOS7 App store search icons](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/115699-ios7-app-store-search-icons.html). Btw, if you check various apps in the App Store, you can see that a lot of them have this common problem, the icon displayed in search results is the incorrect/iOS6 version.

Anybody know what the deal is? This is so annoying.

Comment: Have you left the "old icon" where it was? You should change all icons to fit iOS 7, even if you are planning to still give support to iOS 6 in your app. If you have different versions of the icon in your project folder, that may be the cause.

Comment: As I said, I setup icons with the new `Images.xcassets` folder. In the AppIcon part of this folder, all the icons are clearly labeled with which iOS version and what resolution they are suppose to be.

Comment: Hi, I've got same problem too. Did you sort it out?

Comment: Robert, my solution was to have the iOS 7 border for all icon sizes. This results in the app store showing correct icon, however introduces a small problem which is that the icon will look wrong on iOS 6 devices, which is not as important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were looking for an answer to this problem, this isn't the answer you were looking for. I feel that it is too late in the game for Apple to do anything about this issue, since at this point nobody cares about iOS6. Therefore, the best course of action is to just make all icons for iOS7, meaning if you have a border in your icon, make the roundness of the border match iOS7 for all sizes. This will result in the icon looking slightly weird on an iOS6 device, but at this point that is an extremely minor issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with one of my apps on iOS7. It seems it is an issue on Apple's side.
I had everything setup correctly in Xcode, but the icon displayed in search results was wrong.

In the last update I finally solved the problem. It seems Apple always takes "Icon@2x.png" for search results on the App Store. It doesn't matter what you set in Images.xcassets or Info.plist. Apple will probably fix the problem soon, for the moment you can just replace the "Icon@2x.png" file.

Comment: I am going to try this approach soon, I was hoping not to do this as this would cause the icon to be displayed incorrectly in iOS 6 devices, but I guess that is less of an issue now since most users are on iOS 7.

Comment: @Sylv, thank you but how did you find that Icon@2x.png is the one (and not, for example, Icon-72@2x.png or one of the other ones)?